# Barnes G-function integral formula

Tags: integration

I want to prove this equality: $$\log G(z+1)= -\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t}}{t(1-e^{-t})^2} \left(1-zt-\frac{z^2t^2}{2} -e^{-zt}\right)\mathrm{d}t +\frac{z^2}2 (1 +\gamma) -\frac{3 }{2} \ln\left(\frac{2 \pi}{2}\right) ,$$ with $\Re(z+1)>0.$
So far I have arrived at $$ \log G(z+1)= -\int_0^z \log\Gamma(z) \mathrm{d}z +\frac{z}{2} -\frac{z^2}{ 2}+\frac{z}{2} \ln(2\pi) + z \log \Gamma(z) .$$
I tried to use the definition of the $\Gamma$ function to move forward but I don't get the desired equality, any leads so that I can move forward please?